# Помогите разобраться с кодировкой nodejs

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, кодировка

```
var text = "Привет";
request("http://site.ru/i.php?t="+text, function(error, res, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Выводит: `@825B`

Файл i.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo $_GET["t"];
?>
```

Comment: А что выводит `console.log(typeof body)`?

Comment: console.log(typeof body) : string

Comment: А если заменить `echo $_GET['t']` на `echo iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $_GET['t']);`?

Comment: Выводит "ээээээ". Дело не в php. Я это слово "привет" пробую отправлять по API в телеграмм. Туда уходят данные в UTF-8. (если была бы другая кодировка, то вышла бы ошибка). В телеграмме мне тоже вместо "привет" выводится "@825B"

Comment: Эм... а сам JS файл в какой кодировке сохранен?! Точно в UTF8?

Comment: Ну и как тест, можно добавить `console.log(text);` до отправки запроса

Comment: console.log(text); выводит "Привет" - там все хорошо. Файл JS сохранен в кодировке UTF-8. Если у файла поменять кодировку на Windows-1251, то ответ приходит уже такой: "??????"

Comment: Ну, значит, это магия :) Возможно кто-то еще даст совет лучше моих.

Comment: Попробуйте явно использовать URL encode или  попробуйте слать post запрос

Answer (score 1):

Всегда явно кодируйте данные.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1693

Проблема примерно в этом куске кода:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.x/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L131-L134

Ваш запрос в результате перекодируется как `binary` и получается такая каша:

```
> new Buffer('Привет', 'binary').toString()
'\u001f@825B'
```

Answer (score 0):

Так должно работать

```
request("http://site.ru/i.php?t=" + encodeURIComponent(text),
```